# Woocommerce - custom variable product options

Tags: wordpress, customization, woocommerce

smart people I have what might be a challenge at least for me anyway.

I'm using Woocommerce for ecommerce site but need to customize the Variable Product options to include more relevant variation info for my products. By default, Woocommerce gives you the following options for variable products, SKU, Stock Qty, Regular Price, Sale Price, Weight, Dimensions (L×W×H) , Shipping class. Can you show me how I would go about removing these options and adding my own. I need options like Construction, Max Load Single (kg), Max Load Dual (kg),Max Speed (km/h).... I need this so each size attribute can have different variables.

After adding the custom fields to the tab I also need them to display on the front end Addional info tab.

Any ideas?

Image of panel need customised is

[image: here]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need to hook into:

```
woocommerce_process_product_meta_variable
```

So something like this will do the trick:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta_variable', 'new_custom_field_here', 10, 1 );

function new_custom_field_here( $loop, $variation_data ) { ?>

      <label>New Field</label>
      <input name="new_field_[<?php echo $loop; ?>]" value="<?php echo $variation_data['_new_field'][0]; ?>"/>
    
<?php }
```

This will create a new field. You will then need to save this data:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta_variable', 'save_new_custom_field', 10, 1 );

function save_new_custom_field( $post_id ) {
if (isset( $_POST['variable_sku'] ) ) :
    $variable_sku = $_POST['variable_sku'];
    $variable_post_id = $_POST['variable_post_id'];

    $new_field = $_POST['new_field'];
    
    for ( $i = 0; $i < sizeof( $variable_sku ); $i++ ) :
        $variation_id = (int) $variable_post_id[$i];
        if ( isset( $new_field [$i] ) ) {
            update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_new_field', stripslashes( $new_field [$i] ) );
            update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_parent_product', $post_id );

        }
        
    endfor;

endif;
}
```

I hope this gets you on the right track!

Comment: you meant 'new_custom_field_here' not 'function new_custom_field_here' but still it gives me no outcome in admin

Comment: @Fanky this answer is now 7 years old...the hooks have more than likely changed with the lastest WooCommerce